# Issue with jQuery Sticky Nav and responsive design

Tags: jquery, navigation, responsive-design, sticky, browser-width

I'm having a problem I can't fix with this code I'm using to achieve a sticky navigation when scrolling down the page.

I want the js not to do anything If the browser window width is lower than 720px, it works but only on first page load. I mean if I resize the window while the sticky nav is active, It still remains active even when I resize the window under 720px. Here's the jQuery:

```
//Sticky Navi
jQuery(function($) {

// grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('.main-navigation').offset().top;
var browserWidth = $( window ).width();

// our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
var sticky_navigation = function(){
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

    // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
    // otherwise change it back to relative
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top && browserWidth > 720) { 
        $('.main-navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'z-index':999999, 'opacity': 0.9, 'box-shadow': '0px 3px 5px #393939' })
    } else {
        $('.main-navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'opacity': 1, 'box-shadow': 'none' }); 
    }   
};

// run our function on load
sticky_navigation();

// and run it again every time you scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
     sticky_navigation();
  });

});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can't do much without your HTML and CSS to go with it.

Comment: I can't see how html and css are relevant for the issue. The script works I just need to know how to unload/disable the function in jQuery when the window is resized under a specific width.

Comment: HTML and CSS are always relevant to any javascript or jquery that changes the HTML and CSS of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment, I can't do much without your HTML and CSS, but here's something that works. You had a weird function that needed fixing.

```
function sticky_navigation() {

// grab the initial top offset of the navigation
var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('.main-navigation').offset().top;
var browserWidth = $(window).width();
var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

// if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top,
// otherwise change it back to relative
if ((scroll_top > $('.main-navigation').height()) && (browserWidth > 720)) {
    $('.main-navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'z-index':999999, 'opacity': 0.9, 'box-shadow': '0px 3px 5px #393939' });
} else {
    $('.main-navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'opacity': 1, 'box-shadow': 'none' });
    }   
};

// and run it again every time you scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    sticky_navigation();
});
```

Fiddle with junk HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/cm4t6/

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works same way as before though. If I resize the window while the page is scrolled it also affects the mobile view (and I don't want that). I'm not a jQuery expert but I think I need something to check if the window is resized also after the script has loaded.

Comment: Because you're only calling the function when the window scrolls. If you want to call the function when the window resizes, you'll need to add in a hook to the .resize() trigger.

Comment: I've menaged it to work eventually. A major issue was caused by another jQuery plugin (that handles the small menu) that changes nav class names. Loading the script before that one and adding the .resize() trigger fixed the problem. Thank you Ghlitch.